# How to up a down backend in pgpool, without restart

Tags: pgpool

Is there a easy way to UP a DOWN backend, withour restart pgpool? A command line or something...

for example, when /var/log/postgresql/pgpool_status turn:

```
up
up
up
```

into:

```
up
down
up
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pcp_attach_node](http://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/en/html/pcp-attach-node.html) to attach the disconnected backend node without restarting the Pgpool-II

Comment: Thank you! I just had to setup PCP before.